# Solution to $\int_{0}^{y} x^{-a} \exp \left[- \frac{(b - cx^{-d})^2}{2} \right] dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Is there a solution to this integral?

$$\int_{0}^{y} x^{-a} \exp \left[- \frac{(b - cx^{-d})^2}{2} \right] dx,$$
where $a > 0$ and $d > 0$.

Comment: Get rid of $b,c$ with a change of variable then look at the definition of the Gamma function (which has no closed form)

Comment: @blamethelag, please, could you elaborate on your comment? perhaps, post it as an answer, please?

Comment: I talked too fast this is not the way out. Still you can do a change of variable to drop the $c$ and the $d$

Comment: What have you [tried](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)?

Comment: @TymaGaidash, I've just posted/answered what I have found.

Comment: Rephrased comment, I have found a [similar Nutall and Toronto Q functions](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.03447.pdf), but hot exactly the sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using series expansion, change of variable (x=1/z) and Eq. (3.381.9) of the book: "I. S. Gradshteyn and I. M. Ryzhik, Table of Integrals, Series, and Products, 8th ed. Burlington, MA, USA: Academic Press, 2015", I was able to find this solution:

$$\int_{0}^{y} x^{-a} \exp \left[- \frac{(b - cx^{-d})^2}{2} \right] dx 
\\= \exp(-b^2/2)  \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(bc)^k}{k!} \Gamma\left(\frac{dk+a-1}{2d}, \frac{c^2 y^{-2d}}{2} \right)\frac{1}{2d(c^2/2)^{\frac{dk+a-1}{2d}}}.$$

I've run some simulations and it works.However, there might be some convergence problems for some values, I think so.

Comment: You can examine the convergence by using the asymptotics of $\Gamma(a,z)$ for large $a$ and fixed $z$. Combine http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.2.E3 and http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.11.E4

Answer (score 1):

First is a way to “decompress” the integrand as recommended by @blamethelag. Use $x=c^{d-1} u\implies dx=c^{d-1}du$ assuming $a,d>0\ne c$:

$$\int_{0}^{y} x^{-a} \exp \left[- \frac{(b - cx^{-d})^2}{2} \right] dx=\int_0^{yc^{1-d}}\left(c^{d-1} u\right)^{-a}e^{-\frac{\left( b-{c\left(c^{d-1}u\right)^{-d}}\right)^2}{2}}c^{1-d}du= c^{a-ad-d+1}\int_0^{yc^{1-d}}u^{-a}e^{-\frac{\left(b-{u^{-d}}\right)^2}{2}}du $$

Also let $u=v^d\implies du=dv^{d-1}\,dv$. In order to change the bounds, we need to assume $d>0$ to get an $\infty$ in the lower bound as $v_\text{lower}=0^{-d}\to\infty$:

$$c^{a-ad-d+1}\int_0^{yc^{1-d}}u^{-a}e^{-\frac{\left(b-{u^{-d}}\right)^2}{2}}du= c^{a-ad-d+1}\int_\infty^{y^{-d}c^{1-2d}}\left(v^d\right)^{-a}e^{-\frac{\left(b-{\left(v^d\right)^{-d}}\right)^2}{2}}dv^{d-1}dv =-d c^{a-ad-d+1}\int^\infty_{y^{-d}c^{1-2d}}v^{d-ad-1}e^{-\frac{(b-v)^2}{2}}dv $$

Therefore:

$$\int_{0}^{y} x^{-a} \exp \left[- \frac{(b - cx^{-d})^2}{2} \right] dx = -d c^{(a+1)(1-d)}\int^\infty_{y^{-d}c^{1-2d}}x^{d-ad-1}e^{-\frac{(b-x)^2}{2}}dx $$

Here is a function which almost works called the [**Nuttall Q-function**](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.03447.pdf) incorporating the
[Modified Bessel Function of the First Kind](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html) into its definition:

$$Q_{m,n}(a,b)\mathop=^\text{def}\int_b^\infty  x^m e^{-\frac{x^2+a^2}{2}}\text I_n(ax)dx$$

which would work if we could find a value such that:

$$\text I_n(ax)=e^{-\frac{bx}2}$$

Also see

> [these other related functions](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bbm%3A978-0-387-47694-0%2F1.pdf).

No worries, we can just use a more general function like the [**Incomplete Fox-Wright function**](https://advancesindifferenceequations.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s13662-020-03067-0)

$$\,_pΨ_q^{(\Gamma)}\left[\,^{(a_1,A_1,x),(a_2,A_2),…(a_p,A_p)}_{\quad(b_1,B_1),…,(b_p,B_p)}\ t\right]\mathop=^\text{def}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(a_1+A_1n,x)\prod\limits_{j=2}^pΓ(a_j+A_jn)t^n}{\prod\limits_{j=2}^p \Gamma(b_j+B_jn)n!}$$

Therefore, we get the very simple closed form for $c,d\ne0$:

$$\int_{0}^{y} x^{-a} \exp \left[- \frac{(b - cx^{-d})^2}{2} \right] dx 
\\= \exp(-b^2/2)  \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(bc)^k}{k!} \Gamma\left(\frac{dk+a-1}{2d}, \frac{c^2 y^{-2d}}{2} \right)\frac{1}{2d(c^2/2)^{\frac{dk+a-1}{2d}}}= \frac{e^{-\frac{b^2}2}}{2d \left(\frac{c^2}2\right) ^ \frac{a-1}{2d}}  \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \Gamma\left(\frac{a-1}{2d}+\frac{1}{2}k, \frac{c^2}{2 y^{2d}} \right) \frac{\left(\frac{4b}{c^3}\right)^k}{k!}=  \frac{\,_1Ψ_0^{(\Gamma)}\left[\,^{\left(\frac{a-1}{2d},\frac12,  \frac{c^2}{2 y^{2d}}\right)}\ \frac{4b}{c^3}\right]}{2d e^{\frac{b^2}2} \left(\frac{c^2}2\right) ^ \frac{a-1}{2d}}=\\ \frac{\,_1Ψ_0^{(\Gamma)}\left[\begin{matrix}{\left(\frac{a-1}{2d},\frac12,  \frac{c^2}{2 y^{2d}}\right)}\\—\end{matrix}\ \frac{4b}{c^3}\right]}{2d e^{\frac{b^2}2} \left(\frac{c^2}2\right) ^ \frac{a-1}{2d}}  $$

There may be a typo, but I hope this closed form helps.

> Tell me if there are any decomposition formulas for the Incomplete Fox-Wright function as we would love to know.

Please correct me and give me feedback!

Comment: Expanding the exponential is problematic because it will not converge uniformly on the region of integration and hence you cannot integrate term-by-term.

Comment: @Gary That is why I left it in the integral form. Thanks.

Comment: $I_\nu(z)$ always grows exponentially for $z>0$.

Comment: The interest for the $\Psi^{(\Gamma)}$ function is much lower than before as it is an old answer